# TEZ parameter equivalent to "mapreduce.map.failures.maxpercent"

Tags: hadoop, hive, parameters, mapreduce, apache-tez

In previous versions of Hadoop where MR is used we have a set parameter for ignoring certain percentage of vertex failures.In the new versions where MR is deprecated, is there any equivalent parameter for mapreduce.map.failures.maxpercent in TEZ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I this [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TEZ-3271) new configuration property `tez.vertex.failures.maxpercent` was added:

> Float value. Specifies the allowable percentage in the range
>   0.0-100.0f of task failures per vertex that will allow the vertex to succeed with failures. Default is 0.0f

See also [TezConfiguration.java](https://github.com/apache/tez/blob/master/tez-api/src/main/java/org/apache/tez/dag/api/TezConfiguration.java)

Comment: I tried to use the parameter but its throwing an error out "Error while processing statement: Cannot modify tez.vertex.failures.maxpercent at runtime. It is not in list of params that are allowed to be modified at runtime". Please let me know if I had to set any other properties for this to work

Comment: @Pruthvi Maybe whitelist will help: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/It-is-not-in-list-of-params-that-are-allowed-to-be-modified/td-p/182820